# How to query by subcategory and, if there are fewer than 10 posts in that subcategory, fill out with posts from parent category

Tags: categories, query

I want to query all posts by subcategory and, if there are less than 10 posts in that subcategory, I want to return posts from the parent. If there are still not 10 posts, I want to fill out the remaining with any posts.

I have this, but the problem is it will give me the same posts as dupes:

```
$post_category = get_the_category();
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'post__not_in'   => array(get_the_ID()),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat' => $post_category[0]->term_id,
];
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if (count($query->posts) < 10) {
    $args['posts_per_page'] = 10 - count($query->posts);
    $args['cat']            = $post_category[0]->category_parent;
    $query_parent_category  = new WP_Query($args);
    $query->posts          += $query_parent_category->posts;
}

if (count($query->posts) < 10) {
    $args['posts_per_page'] = 10 - count($query->posts);
    $query_all  = new WP_Query($args);
    $query->posts          += $query_all->posts;
}
```

I know there's a better way to do this that I'm missing. What is it?